# advanced search name also search in custom attribute

Tags: magento2

So, I made some custom attribute in admin panel, it's `province`, `city` etc. how to make the field `name` of the search form also search on those attribute?

Comment: Enable advance search and catalog search in agtribute options

Comment: advanced search is already enabled. please note, that I want to when user type in eg. `chicago` in `name` field it will also search that query in province and city. so, not typing in province or city field.

Answer (score 0):

The search query for this form is defined in `app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml`. These xml files (also almost any other xml file in Magento) are collected from all modules and merged in one big xml. This way you can add additional queries and filters to existing search queries. So, you need to:

- Create `etc/search_request.xml` file in your module
- Add `matchQuery`
  query to `advanced_search_container` in a way similar to other
  queries from original file.